# equally spaced list items (vertical justify)

Tags: css

I have a list of 12 links in a div with a height of 325px.
Is there a way to equally distribute the list vertically so that it fills up the entire height of the div box? Like a vertical justify.

I've tried specifying the line-height so it reaches the full 325px height, but it's off by a few px and it's bugging me.

I hope this is clear...thanks!

**EDIT**

I want it to look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WwgSn/ but with less dumb code!

Comment: Can you show what you have so far? http://jsfiddle.net/. Do you need to support IE7?

Comment: I want it to look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WwgSn/

The list has to line up with an image that's next to it.  But the only way I can get it to work is to fake it with absolute positioning, and with decimal point values for line heights, which isn't really a solution.  Rounding down/up the line height values ends up making it off by just a few px and makes the layout look bad. ug.

Answer (score 0):

A lot will depend on how you want the links to look. For example, do you want each of the 12 links to have a background color. Do you want the links to have a border? If you want the links to have a background or border (or both), do you want there to be a specific height of the links, so there can be spacing between them?

The simplest answer is to divide 325 by 12 (which is 27.0833333). And then set the <li> height and line-height to it (round down to 27).

Here is a simple jsfiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/tETcW/43/

Let me know if you wanted to set a specific height on each <li>, the formula for coming up with the exact margin-between each <li> is a smidge trickier.

Comment: I guess what I mean is, using your jsfiddle example, I want the link1 to be at the very top of the div box, and the link12 to be aligned to the bottom of the div, with all the links in between evenly spaced. The text at both the top and bottom of the list would be at the same "level" as the top and bottom of the dark grey box next to it.

I'm now thinking there isn't really a way to do this with line heights, and I'll have to fake it another way.  It's just that the site design is very grid based, so any small misalignments are very noticeable.

Comment: well I have this js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tETcW/60/ but there is maybe 1px underneath the last link...I wouldn't spend much time trying to get it better than that...If you do need it, look into using Positioning, absolute or relative for each link and do the math to find the exact coordinates. Or use javascript to do it for you

Answer (score 0):

I put together some JS that dynamically set the height of the li's. It means that its all calculated and works of parent divs height.

```
var foo = $(".parentDiv").height(),
    bar = $("ul li"),
    baz = foo / bar.length;

bar.each(function(){
    $(this).height(baz);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tETcW/65/